# Batch file not working correctly

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here's my batch file:

```
@echo on
G2GsiBridge_ROOT=C:\Users\123\Documents\testing\Debug
"%G2GsiBridge_ROOT%\Gsi" %1 %2
```

When I double click it the console pop up for a fraction of a second and then disappears. Gsi.exe doesn't run. I'm curious if I'm messing up the syntax somewhere.

Also, my gsi.exe takes 2 command line arguments and i'm confused on what %1 and %2 are suppose to do. I'm pretty sure they pass the arguments in, but aren't they empty currently? Do I need to set 1 and 2 to something in order for my program to run correctly?

Thanks

Comment: _"When I run it the console pop up for a fraction of a second and then disappears"_ - then start it from an already running command prompt and read the output.

Comment: Hm... your application takes two arguments, but you provide none... yes, `%1` and `%2` represent the arguments passed to the batch file...

Comment: @CodeCaster Isn't the point of using a batch file is to avoid doing that?

Comment: @ConnorMote:  isn't the point of troubleshooting to see what happens? For troubleshooting run from an already running command prompt - once it works, you can start it however you want.

Comment: @Stephan Since I already know that gsi.exe works (besides the fact that it crashes because it wants cmd arguments) I don't see how that would trouble shoot anything. I guess I wasn't clear enough with the question.

Comment: It's troubleshooting because then you can read the output without the window closing on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line is missing the `set` keyword:

```
set G2GsiBridge_ROOT=C:\Users\123\Documents\testing\Debug
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the first problem. However, the program is crashing because I believe it is expecting command line arguments and I'm just sending it an empty 1 and 2. Could I be right and if so, how do I pass in real arguments (the program is expecting a port# and an interface name).

Comment: @ConnorMote You don’t explain how you are running the batch file. Are you simply double-clicking the file? Yeah, that won’t work, since you need to provide the parameters. You need to either change the `%1` and `%2` to the actual values you want, or open a `cmd` window, `cd` to the appropriate directory, then type the name of the batch file followed by the two parameters.